# Assembly if AND

Tags: assembly

I have a problem with assembly assignment:

> Write a program that will write the numbers 7-15 in the data segment,
>   starting from offset 200h, and then using a loop and compare them to
>   read data from memory and the DX will insert the sum of numbers
>   divisible by four.

Here is my code, and it doesn't work. I'm a beginner in assembly language. Could someone please help me?

```
mov ax,data
mov ds,ax
mov cl,07d 
mov ch,015d
mov [bx],200h

c:
mov [bx] ,cl
inc cl
inc bx
cmp cl,ch
jne c

c1:
mov cl,[bx]
if
AND ax, 3h
add dx, ax
inc cl
inc bx 
else
jmp c1
end if
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no `IF` or `ELSE` instructions in... well... *any* assembly language.  If you want an equivalent if/else block in assembly, you need to compose the correct sequence of instructions.

e.g., Consider this C code:

```c
if (a == 0)
{
    b = 1;
}
else
{
    b = 2;
}
```

The appropriate assembly code would look something like this:

```
    cmp eax, 0
    jne anotzero
aiszero:
    mov ebx, 1
    jmp endifblock
anotzero:
    mov ebx, 2
    jmp endifblock
endifblock:
    nop
```

Comment: i wrote this in my programme but stil does not work.

Comment: If you can't get this to work, then I'm afraid I can't be of any more help in this matter.

Comment: @user1011868 your question indicates you need to program an i286 CPU/16bit program. eax and ebx are 32bit registers. Please state your target platform in your question! (Jeff's answer is very good. If you did read your literature, you'd understand it.)

Comment: that is not completely true :) MASM uses .IF and .ELSE :)

Comment: @androslav: Well those aren't real assembly instructions, those are just some of MASM's high-level directives ("macros") to create that construct.  Instructions like these will be generated in their place.  Hence then name, _Macro_ Assembler.  ;)

Comment: @Jeff Mercado I know :) I just feel like being a smartas* sometimes! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing BX register in c loop, then forgot to assign 200h again. then it goes on icrementing and becomes 209h and more but you need it start from 200h again.

```
jne c
**mov [bx],200h** add this.
c1:
mov cl,[bx]
```

Comment: ok i correct something you propose but i still have a problrm wit the condition. if else end if. what i miss to write in my code??  tnx

Comment: On assembly level there are so ifs. There are branches. You test something and jump to an arbitrary label, if the tests holds true.